# SimpleModal and Jquery (How to do open and closing animations)?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

There's two examples near the bottom of the page that show how to either do open or closing animations.

I'm pretty new to jquery. How can I declare both onOpen and onClose? (I've only been able to get one to work at a time.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.basic').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal(
            {
                onClose: function (dialog)
                {
                    dialog.container.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    });

});
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the `onOpen` option in your object mapping:

```
function myOpen(dialog){
    // Do something with the dialog
}
function myClose(dialog){
    // Do something else with the dialog
} 
$('#basic-modal-content').modal({ onOpen: myOpen, onClose: myClose });
```

Or, you can declare the callbacks in the function call like you did in your post:

```
$('#basic-modal-content').modal({
    onOpen: function(){
        // Do something with the dialog
    },
    onClose: function(){
        // Do something else
    }
 });
```

Comment: Is there a way to set it to work with any modal window? Instead of having to declare it every time for every dif (in this case "basic-modal-conent') is there a way to make the animation be the same for all modal windows?

also, for some reason when I put onOpen and onclose the way you suggested, when the window opens it closes right afterwards

Comment: To target all modals, you should just add a 'modal' class to each DOM element you need it on, then target $('.modal'). Can you post your exact code for onOpen, and onClose?

Comment: The thing is, each one is unique. For example there may be two links on a page. One link titled "Register" another titled "contact". The link titled register should open the div with id of "simplemodal-register" and the contact should open "simplemodal-contact". I'm going to have several of these on the website, so I'd rather condense the code by not rewriting it for every div I need.

The example code is here: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#example-10

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are the differences between each unique modal?  If you aren't changing the css or size of the modal, then the class implementation @bobthabuilda mentions would be the best way.  Otherwise you are going to have to style each modal separately, which seems like bad design in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your latest comment, I agree with ryanulit. However, here's one solution to achieve  what you've described. You could do something like this for contact and register links:

```
<a href="#">Contact</a>
<a href="#">Register</a>
```

You could do something like this:

```
$('a[href=#]').click(function(){
    // Will reference 'contact' or 'register'
    var modalType = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $('simplemodal-' + modalType).modal({ /* Options... */ });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to one of the questions:

If you want to set an option once for all modals to use, you can do it with:

```
$.modal.defaults.onClose = function (dialog) {
     // your code
     $.modal.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric. Thank you for a great product! I am curious about the onClose method. I have code similar to @Nathan "onClose" call below. When I call the modal to pop-up on document.ready() and then close it with a close button, then call it again with a button click from another element on the page, and then try to close it again with the same close button click it will not fire? ESC key always works though. Is there something I am missing? I can create another question thread and a fiddle if you would like an example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just combine the two examples he provides [here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/):

// Opening animations

```
$("#sample").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.data.hide();
        dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.slideDown('slow');   
        });
    });
}});
```

// Closing animations

```
$("#sample").modal({onClose: function (dialog) {
    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        });
    });
}});
```

// Combined animations

```
$("#sample").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.data.hide();
        dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.slideDown('slow');   
        });
    });
},
onClose: function (dialog) {
    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        });
    });
}});
```